# Dremel rotary tool: Grinding holes in hardened plastic

Tags: tools, drill, powertools, plastic, cutting

I want to cut/drill/grind a small drainage hole (maybe more than one) in through the base of a plastic terrarium. I don't have a drill on hand but I have a Dremel Micro rotary tool. Is it alright to use one of these bits to do this kind of thing? Which one would be best?

[image: faunarium]
[image: rotary bits]
[image: rotary tool]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dremel will do what you need here. The 2nd bit from the left will work perfectly. It will drill a small pin hole to a larger hole the size of the largest portion of the bit

Comment: Cheers. That one worked alright @ high revs. The others, not so much. I expected it to cut a bit better though; it seemed to melt the plastic more than anything. End result is countersunk.

Comment: @tjt263 Yes, that's a common result with plastic if you don't take your time - heat will build up and it can be nasty trying to get molten/re-hardened plastic out of the bit. Either set a lower RPM, or spray such surfaces with water in future, to keep them cool. A Dremel drill press or jig can make this a lot easier, but I don't recommend the stock Dremel drill press.

Comment: The Dremel drill press is okay, but not compatible with this particular tool because there's no locking collar below the collet.

Comment: Not actually sure what these bits are intended for.